# Substitute (scalar) multiples of a sub-expression

Tags: python, sympy, substitution

I need to identify and replace **multiple** of a sub-expression from an expression:

eliminate *1*x - 3*exp(x)* from *x**2 - 3*x + 6*exp(x)* to give either *x**2 - x* or *x**2 - 3exp(x)*.

I haven't found yet an elegant and correct way to face the problem.
Among my several attempts I tried a recursive application of [`extract_additively`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/core.html?highlight=extract#sympy.core.expr.Expr.extract_additively) but it's not universal and may fail!

What is the right way to "eliminate" multiple of an expression?

```
import sympy as sp
import IPython.display as disp


x = sp.Symbol('x')

yp = x**2 - 3*x + 6*sp.exp(x)

# testing sub-expressions
yhs = [1*x - 3*sp.exp(x), # OK
       5*x - 3*sp.exp(x), # FAIL: coefficient greater than the original
       - 7*sp.exp(x),   #   FAIL: coefficient greater than the original
       ]

# recursive extraction
for yh in yhs:
    yp_mod = yp.expand()

    while yp_mod.extract_additively(yh):
        yp_mod = yp_mod.extract_additively(yh)
    while yp_mod.extract_additively(-yh): # test for opposite sign
        yp_mod = yp_mod.extract_additively(-yh)

    disp.display(yp_mod)

#x**2 - x
#x**2 - 3*x + 6*exp(x)
#x**2 - 3*x + 6*exp(x)
```

Comment: If you don't want the subtraction to fail, then why not just use `-`?

Comment: Consider the problem in an abstract way: you have no clue of the insight of the expression

Comment: @Him I think subtracting is not the right choice. A similar approach would be to divide and then looking for constant values. The latter are those to need to be eliminated... but then it become a nightmare because _sympy_ manage fraction in his way!

Comment: @cards check: [`cse`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/rewriting.html#common-subexpression-detection-and-collection)